# Custom FxCop rule - Integration tests?

Tags: integration-testing, fxcop

I've got a FxCop custom rule and I need to be able to create a integration test. I'm however having a hard time finding decent examples regarding this, since MS changed the API. Osherove's [FxCopUnit](http://file:///C:/Arbejdsfiler/DCFServices/Tools/CustomFxCopRules/CustomCodeAnalysis/bin/TeamAgile.FxCopUnit.Bin/GettingStartedWithFxCopUnit.htm) looks like the perfekt framework, but it also relies on the old FxCop API - Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True unit testing of FxCop rules isn't necessarily worth the investment necessary to build a proper unit testing framework for rules.  Too much depends on the data and logic provided by the FxCop engine itself for the dependency to be mocked without introducing potentially serious deviations from behaviour of the actual engine.  Most folks who test rules run mainly integration tests (including FxCopUnit, despite its name).

If you feel that an integration testing framework for FxCop rules would be useful, there is one included in the [Bordecal FxCop rules framework](http://bordecalfxcop.codeplex.com).  Documentation for its use is in the "The rule testing framework" section at http://bordecalfxcop.codeplex.com/documentation.

Comment: Excellent! I in fact want to create integration tests. I'll alter tags and header. I'll try it out.

Comment: I'm marking yours as an answer since this will resolve my issue. However in the long run, this approch is a little too cumbersome for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

I've also rolled a custom FxCop testing framework based on Roslyn CTP. You can find it in the FxCopContrib project at http://FxCopContrib.codeplex.com/

Just get the latest version of the sources to get it.

Comment: Any rules you've developed are welcome to join the FxCop Contrib project :)

Comment: Hehe - I'll think about making it more generic - pretty concrete caller/callees rule to ensure specific benchmark classes are instantiated.